# After Effects scripting set startTime, unpredictable results. Bug in aftereffects or am i doing it wrong?

Tags: javascript, adobe, extendscript, after-effects

I have a very strange problem while scripting in aftereffects, i wrote a few scripts to perform common tasks and in one of the functions in my latest script i am trying to set the start time of a layer to 0 so the layer will start at the beginning of the composition (so i can perform some more complex tasks in the script).

For this i am using the following code:

```
var theSelectedLayers = app.project.activeItem.selectedLayers;
var arrayLength = theSelectedLayers.length;

for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    var workingLayer = theSelectedLayers[i];
    workingLayer.startTime = 0;
}
```

This works fine in 90% of the compositions i work in but for some strange reason in some compositions the layers are not moved to the start time but they are moved forward in the time-line (the amount varies).

There is no obvious reason for this, the compositions i have used to test this script are near identical. Am i doing something wrong or is there a better way to solve this problem?

I will be grateful for any help! I am really stuck here.

Comment: The start time of a layer is the time when the layer's source starts, the inPoint is the point in the composition when the layer becomes active. I've had problems in the past when I confused the two, because they both do the same thing for layers with no source (solids etc.).

Comment: thxn! at first i replaced the starttime  with inpoint this stretched the layer to the startpoint, not what i was looking for but then i added " workingLayer.startTime = 0; " before inpoint  = 0 and it fixed my script! not shure how, but it works. Do you have an idea how this fixed the issue?

Comment: To get consistent results you probably have to set the startTime and the inPoint explicitly. So you have to work out where the startTime should be to get the inPoint where you want it both in layer time and comp time. Try doing it yourself manually and then work out what needs to happen - after all the script is just doing what you could do with the GUI, so you can sort of step through the behaviour you want.